# How do I rename git tags when fetching

Tags: git

I want to rename git tags during fetching as I have multiple remotes with similar tags that otherwise conflicts
I tried

```
git config --add remote.origin.fetch 'refs/tags/*:refs/tags/myremote/*'
```

And after `git fetch` as expected I got my copies of all my tags named myremote/*
However I also got a version of the tags with the original name
e.g.:
tags on remote:

```
prefix/v1
prefix/v2
```

local tags after fetch:

```
prefix/v1
prefix/v2
myremote/prefix/v1
myremote/prefix/v2
```

I then tried to also add

```
git config --add remote.origin.fetch '^refs/tags/*'
```

But still I got the original name as well as the new name

Comment: Tags (unlike branches) are not remote namespaced. The refspec should be `'refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*'`

Comment: @phd I am not sure I understand what you mean but if I use `git config --add remote.origin.fetch 'refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*'` the name of the tags stays the same locally as on remote and what I am trying to archive is to get a different name locally

Answer (score 0):

Your fetch refspec worked, but the tags you already had at the top level of the ref hierarchy are still there. You can delete them.